# How to install linux 4.8 kernel in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, kernel, hp

My HP Pavilion laptop uses an intel wifi driver which is only supported from kernel 4.8

```
arijit-18:03,Fri Mar 10:~$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
```

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04, how do i install 4.8 kernel in such a that there are no errors?

Pls Help

Comment: Why not upgrade to 16.04? You can install the 4.8 kernel to 14.04, but it won't be supported and won't get security upgrades.

Comment: Our codebase is built on ROS Indigo which is only supported on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You can install any kernel you like from [Ubuntu mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Download and install deb packages according to your arch.

But the 4.8 kernel is not officially supported for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're limited to 14.04 by software you require, what I'd recommend is to correct your hardware problem.  You (or your employer) can buy a USB Wifi transceiver pretty cheaply (though you'll want to avoid the super-cheap Chinese ones).  Make sure the hardware is supported by 14.04 before you buy, plug it into a free USB port, install the correct driver if needed, and you're good to go.  You'll save money, compared to the cost of your time trying to get an unsupported kernel to work and then keep it updated so it's secure.